# Typesafe Play WS as dependency in SBT project

Tags: scala, playframework, frameworks, dependencies, sbt

Since Play Framework 2.3.x, Play WS is a dependent library. Reference:

http://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23

How do I include it in a SBT project?

Answer:

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.3.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Guys for anyone who stumbled it's better to add the following line:

```
libraryDependencies += javaWs
```

Answer (score 1):

For `Build.scala` you should `import play.Play.autoImport._` in order to use the `ws` pattern.
In `build.sbt` you can use it off the bat.